# Is there any reliable way to get the event of Outlook calendar(such as add, update and delete)?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a outlook addin project in c#, which is supposed to listen to the event of outlook calendar. But I found a problem that sometimes my callback functions didn't work. Could someone help me?

I used interop library to get the data from my calendar.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn{
    public Outlook.Application app = null;
    public Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    public Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = null;
    public Outlook.Items appointments = null;
    public Outlook.AppointmentItem deleteItem;
    List<Outlook.Items> allItems = new List<Outlook.Items>();
    List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> allItem = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        app = Application;
        ns = app.GetNamespace("mapi");
        ns.Logon("", "", true, true);
        calendar = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in calendar.Folders)
        {
            var oMailItems = folder.Items;
            allItems.Add(oMailItems);
            oMailItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(appointments_ItemAdd);
            oMailItems.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(appointments_ItemChange);
            oMailItems.ItemRemove += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(appointments_ItemRemove);
            foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in oMailItems)
            {
                item.BeforeDelete += appointments_BeforeItemDelete;
                allItem.Add(item);
            }
        }
        appointments = calendar.Items;
        allItems.Add(appointments);
        appointments.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(appointments_ItemAdd);
        appointments.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(appointments_ItemChange);
        appointments.ItemRemove += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(appointments_ItemRemove);
        foreach (var item in appointments)
        {
            var appointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)item;
            appointment.BeforeDelete+=appointments_BeforeItemDelete;
            String subject = appointment.Subject;
            allItem.Add(appointment);
            Console.WriteLine(subject);
        }
    }
    private void appointments_ItemAdd(object item)
    {
        ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)item).BeforeDelete +=     appointments_BeforeItemDelete;
        saveOperation(item,"A");
    }
```

}

I expect every event to be listened and my callbacks can be executed properly, but the result is that the event sometimes cannot be caught by my code, I can't even summarize a regularity. And the outlook sometimes change the entryId of the calendar items as well.